# Automatic filling of empty spaces (boundaries between polygons) in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro

I have 15 thousand polygons that have empty spaces at the border location. Is there any way to automatically create new boundaries that would connect to each other in ArcGIS Pro?

It would be best if the borders met in the middle (of the empty spaces with interpolation maybe). Smoother borders would also be great if possible. I am looking for any option that would prove a similar result.

Example of what I need (I don't think I can describe the question better than this picture):
[image]

Comment: One other question are all the polygons you are showing within a single layer?

Comment: There are multiple layers (by color). But it can be merged to one layer with multiple polygons.

Comment: For a single layer solution see the integrate tool.  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/integrate.htm

Comment: After I use Integrate tool nothing happened. Still same polygons. I dont know why (no errors).

Comment: Your don't want to use Integrate here.unless you want to randomize the location of the vertices. Create a bounding box polygon. Union to that, then update the gap polygons to have the background polygon value and dissolve. You can then drop the union attributes.

Comment: To compliment @Vince solution your version of ArcPro needs at least a standard license to enable the Union tool to use more than 2 layers at once. Also you would then explode the resulting multipart geometry before attributing and dissolving as suggested.

Comment: Your pictorial example doesn't split the difference (which is exceedingly difficult) and the external part of the bounding box should probably be deleted.

Comment: What you mean with "Create a bounding box polygon" and "update the gap polygons" (any geoprocessing tool for that)? Union tool delete all attribute description from polygons (colors).

Comment: For a bounding box polygon, simply create a new polygon layer with a single feature that fully encloses all of the other polygons that you're interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way to draw middle line between 2 polygons is cost allocation from Spatial Analyst. So 1st union all your polygons **without** gaps.
Convert them **all** to raster of 1 using very small cell size, this is your cost raster. Convert **original** polygons to unique integer values, this is your target.

Run cost allocation which is convertable to polygons and their boundaries (to polylines 1st!) can be smoothed.
Search this site on how to bring attribute (what you call colors) back to newly formed polygons.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I make "Cost Allocation" (your second picture), but with which tool should I create smoothed polygons and their boundaries (your third picture) from this raster?

Comment: Polygon to polyline with default parameter. Smooth line, cartography. Feature to polygon.  Any method to transfer attributes.

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I still can't make one line (border) out of two lines (borders). Smooth line works great, but I still haven't been able to figure out how to make the polygon boundaries (gaps) into just one line. https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2023/05/11/BfRL.png

Comment: Convert coast allocation to polygon, polygons to polyline ,erc

Comment: How did you get the second picture (color 5) - the new center border? That's the part I can't do. My polygon-raster looks like this: https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2023/05/12/Nnzn.png

Comment: See updated post.

Comment: Thank you very much, everything works now. I only have a minor problem with linking the attribute table (original polygons and new polygons). Using "Add spatial join" I made these values only 85%. Some polygons (about 15%) remained without attributes (null values). Is it possible to do even this 15% automatically? https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2023/05/23/UEh4.png

Comment: Run multipart to single part on original polygons. Feature to point (inside). Spatial join points to new polygons